# Show that if A is nonempty, then P ∩ A = ∩ { PX | X ∈ A } - Question 24 Enderton set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm struggling with this exercise 24 from page 33 of Enderton's set theory book

> a) Show that if $A$ is nonempty, then $P \cap A = \cap \{ PX | X \in A\}$
>
> b) Show that $\cup \{PX | X \in A\} \subseteq P \cup A$

My attempt at resolution:

**a)** Take some $x \in P\cap A$, so $x \subseteq \cup$ $P \cap A$ and we know that $\cup P \cap A = \cap A$, then $ x \subseteq \cap A$. And if $X \in A$, also $\cap A \subseteq X$ (I'm not sure of this, but I think the intersection of a set has always equal or less elements than each subset of the set?). And since $ x \subseteq \cap A \subseteq X$ then $x \subseteq X$, and $x \in PX$, but how can I prove that $x \in \cap \{ PX | X \in A\}$? Like, $x$ belonging to $PX$ doesn't guarantee that it also belongs to $\cap PX$, right? Max I could affirm is $x \subseteq \cap PX$, but it doesn't matter for the equality in a).

- Side question: I had the impression that, by nature of the power
  set (alone), it's intersection will always be the empty set, since all of its
  elements differ, I know this sounds a little stupid to ask.

**b)** For any $z \in \cup \{PX | X \in A\}$ also $z \in X$ ($\cup PX = X$) and since $X \in A$, also $X \subseteq \cup A$ that means $X \in PUA$ (applying $a \subseteq b \to a \in Pb$), so can I conclude here that $\cup \{PX | X \in A\} \subseteq P \cup A$
? (If so, how?)

- Under what conditions does equality hold?

For that we need that $P \cup A \subseteq \cup \{PX | X \in A\}$. So, take $x \in P \cup A$ then $x \subseteq \cup P \cup A$ so in order for they to be equal we must have an $X \in A, X = \cup A$? I'm not sure why/if they must be equal and if this works.

I've been  <s>suffering</s>  thinking about this for 6 hours straight so I decided to ask for help. Thanks!

Comment: About your side question : indeed, $\cap P A = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that, by definition,

> $x \in \cap A$ iff $\forall X \in A, x \in X$.
> $x \in \cup A$ iff $\exists X \in A, x \in X$.

**a)** Let $x \in P \cap A$, then $x \subseteq \cap A$, that is to say : $\forall X \in A, x \subseteq X$.
In other words, we have $\forall X \in A, x \in P X$, whence $x\in  \cap \{ PX | X \in A\}$. This shows that $\boxed{P \cap A \subseteq \cap \{ PX | X \in A\}}$

Let $x \in \cap \{ PX | X \in A\}$, then $x \subseteq X$ (ie $x \in P X$) for all $X \in A$. Hence, $x \in P \cap A$. This shows that $\boxed{P \cap A \supseteq \cap \{ PX | X \in A\}}$ whence the claim.

**b)** Let $x \in \cup \{P X \big| \, X \in A\}$. Then there is $X \in A$ such that $x \subseteq X$. Hence, $x \subseteq \cup A$ ie $x \in P \cup A$. This shows that $\boxed{\cup \{PX | X \in A\} \subseteq P \cup A}$.

Comment: ok, now it looks so simple... thank you a lot! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :-)